# Is token possible to make duplication in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I tried to track the code in django rest framework.

I was researching the Token how to generate by DRF.

It's [DRF repository](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/models.py) from github about generating key:

```
def generate_key(self):
    return binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(20)).decode()
```

I have a doubt. Is it possible to make duplication?

Actually, I don't know why it uses `os.urandom` and `binascii.hexlify` can generate unique key. Anyone can explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code doesn't generate unique keys, it generates random (or pseudo-random) keys that are large enough to have a very low probability of being a duplicate.

However, the value is used as the primary key of the model.  In most (if not all) databases, primary keys are unique.  So if it *did* happen to generate a duplicate, it would fail when it tried to commit.  Although in Django's case it may just [assume you were updating the existing record](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert) and change the user the token was assigned to.  It's not something to reasonably worry about, the probability is too low.